# onmouseup event does not work correctly to the slider

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a simle JS slider that reacts to the click by eventListener `onmousedown`. But if you will run the code below, you will see, that the `toddler` does not stop correctly by the eventListener `onmouseup` if we leave the scroll zone `scrollContainer` with holding the left mouse button. The `toddler` will scroll loosely under we will click directly on the him.

What is needed - the `toddler` must stop when we will release the left mouse button (after end eventListener `onmousedown`).

I will be grateful for help.

```js
  var scrollLine = document.getElementById('scrollBar');
  var scrollTog = document.getElementById('toddler');

  function letsMove(event) {

   var coordsHelp = getRealCoords(toddler);
   var shiftX = event.pageX - coordsHelp.left;

   getCoords(event);

    function getRealCoords(toddler) {
     var box = toddler.getBoundingClientRect();

     return {
      left: box.left + pageXOffset
     }
    };

   function getCoords(event) {
    var currentPosition = event.pageX - shiftX;

    if (currentPosition >= 300) {
     toddler.style.left = 300 + 'px';
    } else if (currentPosition <= 104) {
     toddler.style.left = 104 + 'px';
    } else {
     toddler.style.left = currentPosition + 'px';
    }
   };

   scrollContainer.onmousemove = function(event) {
    getCoords(event);
    console.log();
   };

   toddler.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
   };

   toddler.onmouseup = function() {
      scrollContainer.onmousemove = null;
      scrollContainer.onmouseup = null;
      toddler.onmouseup = null;
      toddler.onmousemove = null;
      return false;
   };
  }

  toddler.addEventListener( 'mousedown', letsMove );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
  #scrollContainer {
   width:  400px;
   height: 200px;
   border:  1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 4px;
  }
  #scrollBar {
   width:  200px;
   height: 5px;
   background-color: grey;
   border:  1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 4px;
   margin-top: 24%;
   margin-left: 24%;
  }

  #toddler {
   width: 10px;
   height: 25px;
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: -11px;
   background-color: blue;
   border:  1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 2px; 
   cursor: pointer;  
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="scrollContainer">
  <div id="scrollBar">
   <div id="toddler"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script>
 </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this is almost embarrassingly simple.  The reason you're not getting the `onmouseup` fired when the mouse isn't over the "toddler" is quite literally because the mouse isn't over the "toddler".  (mouse events won't fire for objects that the mouse pointer is not touching).

Simply change the listener to the entire window (in "real" code you may want to add a guard so that you're aware of which slider is expecting the mouse up).

```js
var scrollLine = document.getElementById('scrollBar');
var scrollTog = document.getElementById('toddler');

function letsMove(event) {

    var coordsHelp = getRealCoords(toddler);
    var shiftX = event.pageX - coordsHelp.left;

    getCoords(event);

    function getRealCoords(toddler) {
        var box = toddler.getBoundingClientRect();

        return {
            left: box.left + pageXOffset
        }
    };

    function getCoords(event) {
        var currentPosition = event.pageX - shiftX;

        if (currentPosition >= 300) {
            toddler.style.left = 300 + 'px';
        } else if (currentPosition <= 104) {
            toddler.style.left = 104 + 'px';
        } else {
            toddler.style.left = currentPosition + 'px';
        }
    };

    scrollContainer.onmousemove = function(event) {
        getCoords(event);
        console.log();
    };

    toddler.ondragstart = function() {
        return false;
    };

    /* toddler.onmouseup = function() { */
    window.onmouseup = function() {
        scrollContainer.onmousemove = null;
        scrollContainer.onmouseup = null;
        toddler.onmouseup = null;
        toddler.onmousemove = null;
        return false;
    };
}

toddler.addEventListener('mousedown', letsMove);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
  #scrollContainer {
   width:  400px;
   height: 200px;
   border:  1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 4px;
  }
  #scrollBar {
   width:  200px;
   height: 5px;
   background-color: grey;
   border:  1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 4px;
   margin-top: 24%;
   margin-left: 24%;
  }

  #toddler {
   width: 10px;
   height: 25px;
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: -11px;
   background-color: blue;
   border:  1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 2px; 
   cursor: pointer;  
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="scrollContainer">
  <div id="scrollBar">
   <div id="toddler"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script>
 </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this could be

Bind a `mouseout` event to a specific targetted region and as soon the mouse goes out of that region you should manually trigger or in `javascript` we should say `dispatch` event `mousedown` and that should be bound to the outer slider container so that having multiple sliders on a single page won't affect each other. As soon as you range out of the container the `mouseout` event will dispatch the `toddler` `mousedown` event.

A sample code for preventing the `mouseout` to trigger if a child element is hovered is taken from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amasad/TH9Hv/8/), see your slider below.

```js
var scrollContainer = document.getElementById('scrollContainer');
var scrollLine = document.getElementById('scrollBar');
var toddler = document.getElementById('toddler');

function letsMove(event) {

  var coordsHelp = getRealCoords(toddler);
  var shiftX = event.pageX - coordsHelp.left;

  getCoords(event);

  function getRealCoords(toddler) {
    var box = toddler.getBoundingClientRect();

    return {
      left: box.left + pageXOffset
    }
  };



  function getCoords(event) {
    var currentPosition = event.pageX - shiftX;

    if (currentPosition >= 300) {
      toddler.style.left = 300 + 'px';
    } else if (currentPosition <= 104) {
      toddler.style.left = 104 + 'px';
    } else {
      toddler.style.left = currentPosition + 'px';
    }
  };



  scrollContainer.onmousemove = function(event) {
    getCoords(event);
    console.log();
  };

  toddler.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
  };

  toddler.onmouseup = function() {
    scrollContainer.onmousemove = null;
    scrollContainer.onmouseup = null;
    toddler.onmouseup = null;
    toddler.onmousemove = null;
    return false;
  };


}

function makeMouseOutFn(elem) {
  var list = traverseChildren(elem);
  return function onMouseOut(event) {
    var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
    if (!!~list.indexOf(e)) {
      return;
    }

    // handle mouse event here!
    if ('createEvent' in document) {
      // modern browsers, IE9+
      var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
      e.initEvent('mousedown', false, true);
      toddler.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else {
      // IE 8
      var e = document.createEventObject();
      e.eventType = 'mousedown';
      toddler.fireEvent('on' + e.eventType, e);
    }
  };
}


//quick and dirty BFS children traversal, Im sure you could find a better one                                        
function traverseChildren(elem) {
  var children = [];
  var q = [];
  q.push(elem);
  while (q.length > 0) {
    var elem = q.pop();
    children.push(elem);
    pushAll(elem.children);
  }

  function pushAll(elemArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elemArray.length; i++) {
      q.push(elemArray[i]);
    }

  }
  return children;
}
toddler.addEventListener('mousedown', letsMove);

scrollContainer.addEventListener('mouseout', makeMouseOutFn(scrollContainer), true);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    #scrollContainer {
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    #scrollBar {
      width: 200px;
      height: 5px;
      background-color: grey;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-radius: 4px;
      margin-top: 24%;
      margin-left: 24%;
    }
    
    #toddler {
      width: 10px;
      height: 25px;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: -11px;
      background-color: blue;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-radius: 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="scrollContainer">
    <div id="scrollBar">
      <div id="toddler"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```