# React can't trigger window.onmouseup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouselistener

I have a slider component, which should stop moving after mouse is up. I have went through the forum and my code is very similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510964/onmouseup-event-does-not-work-correctly-to-the-slider)

```
const Slider = ({ mainColour }) => {
  const [cursorPos, setCursorPos] = React.useState(0);
  const [isSliding, setSliding] = React.useState(false);
  const ref = React.useRef();

  const drag = e => {
    console.log("dragging");
    setCursorPos(e.pageY);
  };

  const startDrag = e => {
    setSliding(true);
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
      ref.current.onmousedown = null;
      ref.current.onmouseup = null;
      ref.current.onmousemove = null;
      setSliding(false);
      window.onmouseup = null;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`cursor ${isSliding ? "active" : ""}`}
      ref={ref}
      style={{
        top: `${cursorPos}px`,
        backgroundColor: `${mainColour}`
      }}
      onMouseDown={event => startDrag(event)}
    ></div>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

However, when *startDrag* triggers, the *window.onmouseup* listener doesn't seem to be working and does not stop the slider. Will be appreciated for any insights why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-sunset-8e78r**

React can trigger `mouseup`, you just need to use `window.removeEventListener` for `drag()` when you `mouseup`. That's why you see `dragging` in the console after `mouseup`, you just forgot to unsubscribe from the event :)

`window.onmouseup = null;` is not the same as `window.removeEventListener("mousemove")`.

```
const Slider = ({ mainColour }) => {
  const [cursorPos, setCursorPos] = React.useState(0);
  const [isSliding, setSliding] = React.useState(false);
  const ref = React.useRef();

  const drag = e => {
    console.log("dragging");
    setCursorPos(e.pageY);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSliding) {
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);
    }
  }, [isSliding]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", drag);
      setSliding(false);
    });
  });

  const startDrag = () => setSliding(true);

  return (
    <div
      className={`cursor ${isSliding ? "active" : ""}`}
      ref={ref}
      style={{
        top: `${cursorPos}px`,
        backgroundColor: `${mainColour}`
      }}
      onMouseDown={event => startDrag(event)}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: This code is working in codesandboc, just need to set position to absolute on .cursor as following :  .cursor {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position:absolute
}

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment from artanik, but with a very slight change. Instead of using the useEffect without any dependencies, and constantly adding and removing event listeners from the window object, I would rather only set and unset it when the isSliding changes value. Also it seems that the ref is not used anywhere, so I presume instead of using the window object you could set it only for the element in the ref.

The purpose of triggering the useEffect with an empty array once is to not run it every render. Imagine a component that would have a lot of state changing and data going through it, adding and removing a bunch of event listeners in one go in every render is not needed.

```js
const Slider = ({ mainColour }) => {
  const [cursorPos, setCursorPos] = React.useState(0);
  const [isSliding, setSliding] = React.useState(false);

  ///only do this once, when the component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrag);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", endDrag);
  },[]);

  //and setting and unseting the event as needed
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSliding) {
      window.onmousemove = handleDrag;
    }
    else{
      window.onmousemove = null;
    }

  }, [isSliding]);

  const startDrag = () => setSliding(true);
  const endDrag = () => setSliding(false);

  const handleDrag = (e) =>{
    console.log("dragging");
    setCursorPos(e.pageY);
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={`cursor ${isSliding ? "active" : ""}`}
      style={{
        top: `${cursorPos}px`,
        backgroundColor: `${mainColour}`
      }}
    />
  );
};
```